# Getting error EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink ... in nodejs amplify pull

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-amplify

I've got this error while running `amplify env pull <my_env_name>`
A workaround with run command with admin rights works, but I want to run commands without admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add permissions to create links for the concrete user or for all authenticated users and reboot the machine (maybe logoff/logon enough)[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD62F.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).